# Counting strings of $\{ 0,1 \}$'s of length $n$ s.t. last $k$ bits are equal

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to derive a closed formula for the number of strings of $0$'s and $1$'s of length $n$ such that the last $k \leq n$ bits are all zeros or all ones, and such that there is no other place in the string with $k$ consecutive zeros or ones.

I have tried constructing a recursive formula by "reasoning backward", but the formula is still a mystery.

Comment: When you say *no other place in the string*, does this include places that overlap the last $k$? In other words, are you excluding strings $b_1\dots b_n$ that end in $k+1$ ones, since $b_{n-k}\dots b_{n-1}$ is a second string of $k$ ones?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes, I am excluding those strings. I do not want $k$ consecutive bits to appear anywhere along the string but at the "end."

Comment: Okay: then the question is equivalent to asking how many strings of length $n-k$ do not contain any string of $k$ consecutive zeros or ones. Half of them will end in $0$ and require appending $1^k$, and the other half will end in $1$ and require appending $0^k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is equivalent to asking how many strings of length $n-k$ do not contain any string of $k$ consecutive zeros or ones. Half of these will end in $0$ and require appending $1^k$ to make the desired string of length $n$, and the other half will end in $1$ and require appending $0^k$. Thus, it suffices to find $f(m,k)$, the number of strings of length $m$ that do not contain any string of $k$ consecutive zeros or ones.

Such a string can be thought of as a [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28number_theory%29) of $m$ into parts of size less than $k$, the parts being the blocks of consecutive zeros or consecutive ones. Each composition is represented twice, however, once with a string starting with a block of zeros and once with a string starting with a block of ones. E.g., the composition $3+1+2$ of $6$ is represented by $000100$ and by $111011$. Thus, $f(m,k)$ is the twice the number of compositions of $m$ into parts of size less than $k$.

If define the $\ell$-nacci numbers $a_i^{(\ell)}$ by $a_0^{(\ell)}=a_1^{(\ell)}=\ldots=a_{\ell-2}^{(\ell)}0$, $a_{\ell-1}^{(\ell)}=1$, and

$$a_i^{(\ell)}=a_{i-1}^{(\ell)}+\ldots+a_{i-\ell}^{(\ell)}\tag{1}$$

for $i\ge\ell$, it turns out that $f(m,k)=2a_{m+k-2}^{(k-1)}$, which is easily computed from the recurrence $(1)$.

When $k=2$, for instance, $a_i^{(1)}=1$ for all $i$, and $f(m,2)=2$: the only acceptable sequences are the two alternating sequences of length $m$. When $k=3$, $a_i^{(2)}=F_i$, the $i$-th Fibonacci number, and $f(m,3)=2F_{m+1}$; in this case [Binet’s formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) gives a closed form, and [OEIS A000073](https://oeis.org/A000073) has a really ugly closed form for the $k=4$ case, but for $k>4$ there’s nothing much better than generating functions.

For more information and references see [OEIS A048887](https://oeis.org/A048887) and its references; the specific case $k=5$ is [OEIS A000078](https://oeis.org/A000078).

Answer (score 0):

A nice solution to this kind of problems is given by Odlyzko ["Enumeration of Strings"](http://www.dtc.umn.edu/~odlyzko/doc/arch/string.enumerate.pdf) (in Apostolico and Galil, "Combinatorial Algorithms on Words", Springer, 1985). He derives simple formulas the generating functions. Except for $k = 2$ the formulas for the coefficients are complex.